# Sorted Result Set from DB not apprearring in order while printed in Java

Tags: java, sql, jsp, sorting, collections

Finally narrowed down the problem, here is what my problem is when i execute a SQL which has 'order by' on that and try to print the result set in Java the result set is not sorted.
But when i execute the SQL separately with my SQL developer, I am seeing the ordered result why is that? Is there any option to solve this?

Below mentioned is method I am using

```
List getDBValues(short orderBy) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs   = null;
        List results = nmull;
        String sqlStmt = new String();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            conn = Utilities.getConnection(DB);
            sqlStmt ="SELECT 
                        COLUMN1, 
                        COLUMN2, 
                        COLUMN3, 
                        FROM SAMPLE_TABLE 
                        WHERE 
                        COLUMN1 IN ('10','15') AND 
                        COLUMN3 IN ('1','2') ORDER BY ? ";

            try {
                short orderByObj = 0;

                if(orderBy < 1){
                    orderByObj = Short.parseShort(Math.abs(orderBy)+"");
                    sqlStmt += "DESC";
                }else{
                    orderByObj = orderBy;
                }

                System.out.println("==================== SQL ==================== \n"+sqlStmt);
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);

                ps.setLong(1, orderByObj);

                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next())                               
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3));
            }
            catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return results;

    }
```

Comment: What kind of collection do you store it in?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, its a collection of custom object.

Comment: Do you mean `Collection`? That's an interface, we care about the actual implementation...

Comment: @Ashok, by set do you mean setter methods ?

Comment: It'd be useful to post the code which you're working on.

Comment: I mean do you used `HashSet` in you java code, if you use `HashSet` in your java code, it doesn't maintain order. Can you edit your question with your java code you are working on.

Comment: Sample code is like                                       `Collection<CustomClass> results = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();

while (rs.next()) {
     CustomClass = new CustomClass();

     CustomClass.setValue1(rs.getString("Column_1"));

     CustomClass.setValue2(rs.getString("("Column_2"));

     results.add(CustomClass);
     }`

Comment: You are going to have to show more code. And don't post it in a comment, edit your original question.

Comment: You say you use a `Collection` but your method return a `List`.  Probably the most important part now is the code where you manipulate your `result` object.

Comment: @tom, Please leave that part for now, Now my question is that why the result set is not sorted when I print it, though the query i have given is producing a sorted result when executed through SQL developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a bind variable within the order by statement.

You'll have to append it to the query.

```
        sqlStmt ="SELECT 
                    COLUMN1, 
                    COLUMN2, 
                    COLUMN3, 
                    FROM SAMPLE_TABLE 
                    WHERE 
                    COLUMN1 IN ('10','15') AND 
                    COLUMN3 IN ('1','2') ORDER BY ";            
        try {
            short orderByObj = 0;

            if(orderBy < 1){
                orderByObj = Short.parseShort(Math.abs(orderBy)+"");
                sqlStmt = sqlStmt + " " + orderByObj + " DESC";
            }else{
                sqlStmt = sqlStmt + " " + orderBy ;
            }

            System.out.println("==================== SQL ==================== \n"+sqlStmt);
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())                               
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2)+"\t"+rs.getString(3));
        }
```

Comment: will try the same and let you know whether that has worked out.

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem with you JSP iterations.
Write out the codes you used here. Both i java, jsp.

Use LinkedList kind of collection stuff that stores data with respect to insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being obvious, could it have anything to do with the fact that your SQL query doesn't actually sort the data? Maybe you mean to rewrite with a proper `ORDER` statement, such as, for example:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table ORDER BY column1 DESC
```

Comment: Hi @Nicolas the order by column reference works equally well. `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table ORDER BY 1 DESC`, When i run this query from SQL developer it is giving me sorted result

Comment: Just read up on this and it turns out you're right, `ORDER BY 1` means sort by the value of the first field in the result set. I had no idea!